# two histograms in one plot (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, histogram

Well, I've been looking in this site to make two histograms in one plot. 
I get to

```
ggplot()+geom_histogram(data=etapa1, aes(x=AverageTemperature),col="red")+
geom_histogram(data=etapa2, aes(x=AverageTemperature),col="blue")
```

I've got two histograms with different colours, but I don't get a legend or a label which shows which is each colour. How can I produce it?

Comment: How can we produce your graphs without the data?

Comment: The data doesn't matter in this example. You can use etapa1$AverageTemperature=1:10 and etapa2$AverageTemperature= 7:12, where etapa1 and etapa2 are two dataframes, the data I'm using is large.

Comment: In general you could combine the two `data.frames` and add an extra variable e.g. `etapa` in both data sets and set each value as you want (e.g. *1* and *2* respectively). Then use `fill = etapa` in the `aes()` statement.

Comment: I tried with 1 and 2 and the histogram was in one colour. But with an string " " as you said before it works well. I don't know why, maybe I didn't input well the values.

Comment: If someone has to bother writing two lines of R to duplicate your problem they are 73.2% less likely to attempt your problem. Give them two lines to cut and paste to make an example data set and they are more likely.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to anyone do my example. I want a reply of what I have to do for my problem, that it is combining both datasets. I don't know if this two lines of R are so important or they are very waste of time or effort. Anyway, it is my first question on this site, I hope the first of many, the following questions they will be better done. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As *Spacedman* said it would be better if you could specify your problem more in detail and give an example data set.

So i create a random sample set which simulates a temperature.

```
etapa1 <- data.frame(AverageTemperature = rnorm(100000, 16.9, 2))
etapa2 <- data.frame(AverageTemperature = rnorm(100000, 17.4, 2))

#Now, combine your two dataframes into one.  First make a new column in each.
etapa1$e <- 'etapa1'
etapa2$e <- 'etapa2'

# combine the two data frames etapa1 and etapa2
combo <- rbind(etapa1, etapa2)

ggplot(combo, aes(AverageTemperature, fill = e)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.2)
```

For me it seems more obvious to use a density plot rather than a histogram since temperatures are real numbers.

Hope this helps somehow...

If you don't want to combine the two data.frames it is a bit more tricky...
You have to use `scale_colour_manual` and `scale_fill_manual`. And then define a *variable* for the `fill` statement. This can be linked in the labels section

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_density(data = etapa1, aes(x = AverageTemperature, fill = "r"), alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_density(data = etapa2, aes(x = AverageTemperature, fill = "b"), alpha = 0.3) +
  scale_colour_manual(name ="etapa", values = c("r" = "red", "b" = "blue"), labels=c("b" = "blue values", "r" = "red values")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name ="etapa", values = c("r" = "red", "b" = "blue"), labels=c("b" = "blue values", "r" = "red values"))
```

You can replace `geom_density()` with `geom_histogram()` respectively.

Comment: Yes, you have reason, in fact, I'm doing an histogram and density. This is a perfect solution to my problem, but I can´t do it without combining both datasets? and in the histogram although I put alpha=0.3, I can't see both histograms well. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @Timo Wagner!
Go you know how to change it to percentage histogram?
I tried adding  `aes(y = ..count../sum(..count..))` to histogram as an argument but id dose not help
I have 2 data sent with vast diffrence in number of rows, so showing it on frequencies plot is not helpful

Answer (score 3):

Using @TimoWagner's example:

```
set.seed(1001)
etapa1 <- data.frame(AverageTemperature = rnorm(100000, 16.9, 2))
etapa2 <- data.frame(AverageTemperature = rnorm(100000, 17.4, 2))
```

Here's another way to pack the two data sets together:

```
combdat <- dplyr::bind_rows(list(dat1=etapa1,dat2=etapa2),
                           .id="dataset")
```

Two superimposed histograms:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(combdat,aes(AverageTemperature,fill=dataset))+
   scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","blue"))+
   geom_histogram(alpha=0.5,binwidth=0.1,position="identity")
```